# Find hashed (bcyrpt) code in database and validate it with input (Laravel)

Tags: php, database, laravel, security

I have a simple form with a single input field where you can submit a code (respectively a key). In my database are a bunch of codes stored (in clear text) and if the form input matches with one of those codes you get access to some `Stuff`.

This is the way I am finding out which code has been used to fetch the data

```
$usedCode = Stuff::where('code', $request->code)->get();
```

Now while this works perfect I wanted to add some security to it. Because if somebody has access to my database he can just read the codes.

I tried to `bcrypt` all the codes but then of course the method above does not work anymore.

I know it is not possible to "decrypt" the hashed codes but how can I solve this? 
Or is there no security breach I need to worry about and I should just use the clear text?

Comment: Use Middleware and set permission so that only authorized user can access the data

Comment: That's why you need a user - password combination: You get the correct row from the database with the first and then you can validate the second. And you can store the password using the best available algorithm.

Comment: you could hash it with an unsalted algorithm and store this hash in the db. then when querying you use the same algo before sending it to the db. but this only adds really limited extra security once someone gets access to your db. You could add some pre- and suffixes to the code before hashing then again - but in most cases once the db was accessed you are screwed

Comment: @SagarGautam Yes, that way it would be possible to manage. But  it should be this simple form and everyone should be able to access it.

Comment: @MangoD As Norman Said, If your db is accessed by someone who shouldn't then damage will be done even if some protection is added with customized hashing.

Using middleware doesn't seem well in your case though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather suggest you implement rate limiting. Only one request per minute per visitor and 24 hr block when entering more than 3 invalid codes consecutively. That way they can't spam you with millions of requests to guess codes.

When someone has access to your database all bets are off anyhow. When you find out you've been hacked/database stolen you have other things to worry about.

At this moment it seems your strategy only exists out of a code entering and then you get your Stuff<sup>™</sup>

Add a layer of security/verification by also entering an email, that the user must be logged in, or a second key that was supplied with it or separately that only legit users can have.

You can then hash the codes with user_id/special extra key, or whatever to find the right lookup key. This is only obfuscation, but will make it impossible for people to harvest the codes and then request all the Stuff<sup>™</sup> you have.

When hackers get access to your php code also, all bets are completely off you better wipe slates clean.

**edit**

Another possible idea I had:
Store TheKeyCode<sup>™</sup> + Stuff<sup>™</sup> `primary key`  in database KeyStorage. All that database does is store the codes users use. KeyStorage must have a different user and password than your production database
Store Stuff<sup>™</sup> + Stuff<sup>™</sup>PK in your production database.

Only for key lookup you set up a connection to the KeyStorage database. That script is also the only place where those details are guarded.
That way IF your website has a weakness that someone can pull empty your production database, they won't get the key codes. And if your key code script is secure and contains no flaws, they have no way to connect to the KeyStorage.

```
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=KeyStorage;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'keymaster';
$password = 'zuul';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT stuff_tm_id FROM gozer WHERE code=:code LIMIT 1"); 
    $stmt->bindParam(':code', $code, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
    $stmt->execute(); 
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $stuff = Stufff::find($row['stuff_tm_id']);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Where is the gatekeeper';
}
```

Comment: The rate limiting advise is worth gold, thanks for that! The problem is I cannot add any kind of user authentication. Just imagine that you can only send out these single codes as a message in a bottle. You know the codes but not the users.

Comment: okay, so it's a kind of filesharing kind of deal? kinda like bit.ly. you make it, you get your code, distribute it under your peers/customers and they can get the Stuff™ with that ' promo'  code from the service provided by Mango Could Services™.
I edited my answer for an extra idea I had.

Comment: How did you find out the name of my project? Thanks for the edit, that idea is pretty damn smart!

Answer (score 2):

you can use many ways. i recommend this:
first: `bcrypt` all your codes and then store them in database. never save a non encrypted data in database!
now you can use Laravel's `Hash` Facade for matching the input code:

```
// use Hash namesapce: Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash

foreach(Stuff::all() as $stuff){
   if (Hash::check($request->code, $stuff->code))
       // The codes match...
}
//the codes doesn't match
```

Comment: Thanks! That solution would work but there are more than 2k codes saved in the db and if I use a code at a position above a specific number I get `Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded`. For the first few codes it would work flawless, damn it!

Comment: @MangoD Make method and include it on user's login.